# Move UIView then change circle layer using UIBezierPath that time UIView move automatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, oval

I'm using UIBezierPath for draw **ovalInRect** on UIView its working properly but when I move UIView after I change **ovalInRect** then UIView take old position without change UIView position.

```
    ellipsePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, radiusValue , radiusValue))

    shapeLayer.path = ellipsePath.CGPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
    shapeLayer.sublayers?.removeAll()
    moveView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Now I get ovalInRect on moveView now I move the moveView on screen using **UIPanGestureRecognizer** old place to any other place

```
    func recognizePanGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
    {
    let translate = sender.translationInView(self.view)

    sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x:sender.view!.center.x + translate.x,
        y:sender.view!.center.y + translate.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

   }
```

Then after I update ovalInRect

```
    ellipsePath.removeAllPoints()

    let tempPath = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(ellipsePath.CGPath)

    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(tempPath, nil, CGRectMake(0
            ,0, topA , rightB))
    ellipsePath.CGPath = tempPath!
    shapeLayer.path = ellipsePath.CGPath
    shapeLayer.sublayers?.removeAll()
    moveView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

moveView automatic move to old position (ovalInRect working properly).

I want don't change position when I update ovalInRect time.

Comment: If you put Swift in the question title, why did you tag objective-c?

Comment: Ok i will remove that thank you for suggestion.

Comment: Please avoid using tags in the question's title anyway. Tags go in the tags section, title goes in the title section. ;) Thank you.

Comment: Ok thank you for suggestion.